# Scroll vertical scroll bar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with tree view inside. Div is smaller than tree so on the right side I have vertical scroll bar. When users press some button outside the div, I want to scroll to specified item inside div (I know ID of that item).

How to scroll vertical scroll bar? How to focus on some element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it in two stages:

First, get the position of your element in the div with jQuery function `.scrollTop()`.
Then, set the scrolling position of your div : `$(yourdiv).scrollTop(yourElementPosition)`

Here is the official documentation for the function [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)